# Center a SharePoint Slideshow

Tags: web-part

I manage a client website and they have asked me to insert a slideshow of images of their new office.  I have succesfully created the slideshow, but, you guessed it, I can't center the image on the page (the page is essentially 3 columns of info, and they would like it centered on the center column).  Right now the slideshow is bumped over to the left.  Why there's not a button that says "center" I have no idea.

I've seen other answers to this question that recommend going into the CSS, but I honestly don't understand that stuff, plus, it's not my site so I don't think i can even access or modify it.  I can access the page's HTML however. Is there an HTML code (or another idea out there) that will tell that slideshow to get it's you-know-what in the center of my screen? I have been messing with this way too long!

Much thanks everyone!

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using? are you using the default slideshow provided by SharePoint OR just your custom webpart for slideshow?

Comment: I had to use an iFrame to put my image sliders exactly where I wanted them.

Comment: I should specify that I meant custom sliders. You won't have much control over the slider web part. You'd have to add a table to wiki page as Chris G suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add a table with three columns and add this Web Part in the center column. Within your created table you can change the width for each column, as you wish it.

Let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you have a web part page with the "add web part" buttons at the top of each zone or if you are using a wiki page that is more of a free form text page. With the wiki page you can use a button in the ribbon to organize the "text layout" and pick one that suits your needs. Web parts can be set to be specific sizes or dynamically fit the area they are inserted into. Also the images that load in your slide show web part also might automatically adjust to the size of the web part depending on the settings.

Sometimes inserting tables can be an alternate way of organizing content on a page if none of the layouts work for you.

Comment: I definitely have the "Add web part" buttons, so, not using the wiki.  The table was a great suggestion and I now have a centered slideshow! I'm wondering now - does anyone know how to increase the size of the pictures?  One problem on my page the table has caused is that there is quite a bit of white space around the slideshow now.  I think I can fix that if the pictures get larger.  Increasing file size did not seem to work.  Thanks for all the help, it is so appreciated. I owe you all!

Comment: it can be tricky - are all the photos in your slide show the same size? if they very I bet the slide show adjust as it goes to 'resize' them to fit in the web part. Also you can resize the web part to give it more height or width, however sometimes scroll bars appear with you do this. Google search HTML Tables and there are some 'padding' and 'spacing' parameters you can include to be sure your table isn't take up any space you don't want. :)
HTML Tables: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp (see cell padding and spacing)